# What's wrong with "this" pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

So, i decided to create a collision detection function in my game and i put it into the class of enemies. Then i put it to "enemy.cpp" and i used "this" pointer.
The code:

```
if(((this->sprite.getPosition().y + this->sprite.getTextureRect().height) >= blocklist[i].sprite.getPosition().y) &&
(this->sprite.getPosition().y  <= blocklist[i].sprite.getPosition().y))
```

This gives me SIGSEGV segmentation error. I can't find what could be the problem in this line, here is the enemyclass for reference.

```
class enemyclass
{
public:
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sf::Sprite bubble;
    //PROPERTIES
    float xspeed, yspeed;
    int x, y;
    float health;
    bool colR, colL, colU, colD;
    int skin;
    void detectCollisions(int blocksize);
};
```

and the blockclass that i made a vector of to use as a list of enemies:

```
class blockclass
{
public:
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    int x, y;
};
```

I would be very thankfull for an answer since i can't find out what's wrong.

Comment: How do you *call* the function?

Comment: The implication to me is that either `this->sprite` or `blocklist[i].sprite` is a null pointer.

Comment: I would check that your value of `i` is always valid with respect to `blocklist`.

Comment: Try removing `this->` as it is not necessary in member functions.  If you still have a problem, your issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews this may not be necessary, but it should never cause an error :-/. Whats happening here is as others have pointed out, either the pointer being used to call the class is not initialized, block list is not being accessed correctly, or something in sprite is not being initialized. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409005/what-actually-happens-when-calling-a-getter-function-for-an-instance-variableth/20409363#20409363

Comment: What does getPosition() return?

Comment: I call the function by "void playerclass::detectCollisions(int blocksize)
{"

Comment: And getPosition().x will return a int, x position of sprite and ().y will do same for y position.

Comment: We need to see how you're *calling* detectCollisions. For example, if you did this: `enemyclass *e = NULL; e->detectCollisions(0);`, the `this` pointer would be NULL...

Comment: for(int a = 0; a < enemysize; a++)
        {
            enemylist[a].detectCollisions(enemysize);
        }

Comment: After removing this-> it still gives me a SIGSEGV error.

Comment: Could it be that my collision detection function is in another file and to fix some problems i forward declared blocklist vector in that file, which is empty ?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but in an expression like `a + b >= c && d <= e` you don't need parentheses around the expressions on either side of the `&&`.

Comment: It's not very easy to solve this with the given information. You should chop this statement up to see where the segfault comes from. For example, before this line, make a call to blocklist[i].sprite.getPosition() and see if you get a segfault on that line.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, if some complicated instruction causes an error, split it into smaller parts and see, in which part the error arises:

```
if( this->x == 0) // changes nothing
    x = 0;        // but validates 'this'
int thisy = sprite.getPosition().y;
int thish = sprite.getTextureRect().height;
sf::Sprite &that = blocklist[i].sprite;
if( that.x == 0) // validate 'that'
    that.x = 0;
int thaty = that.getPosition().y;
if(thisy + thish >= thaty && thisy <= thaty) {
    // ......
}
```